# Set multiple component on click button - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm already develop a timer on which we can enter a name and time in seconds to start the timer.

I want now to create a button and if I click, it display another timer with name, and time in seconds.

I don't know how I can do this...

Here is the timer with the inputs... https://jsfiddle.net/q806zeps/37/

I think if I can duplicate this `ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('timer'));` but I thonk it's not possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at this [code](https://jsfiddle.net/q806zeps/41/), hope it solves your problem.

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
         counter : 1
        }
     }
  //add timer code by oneshubh
  addTimer(){
            this.setState({counter: this.state.counter+1})
  }
  render(){ 
var timerDom = [];
  for(var i = 0;i<this.state.counter;i++){
    timerDom.push(<Wrapper />)
  }
  return (
        <div>
          {timerDom}
          <button onClick={()=>this.addTimer()} >add timer</button>
        </div>);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array on the state of `Wrapper` to track the individual timers within your application.

```
state: {
    timers: []
}
```

Clicking the button, adds an object into your state with your current keys.

```
{
      libelle: 'Input name',
      seconds: 10
}
```

Iterate over this array to render you `Minuteur` components by passing the correct index.

Here is an updated fork of your fiddle. [Creating timers using an array](https://jsfiddle.net/jagzviruz/60tgkswc/15/)

Comment: Yes, but in your fork the name of the timer is not keeping. He disseapear ;(

Comment: Right missed a step .. take a look at the updated version. https://jsfiddle.net/jagzviruz/60tgkswc/16/